# Calling a function from object

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script

I retrieve date by calling

```
event[0].getDateCreated() // output in GMT
```

but I want it to Local

I do not want to convert to local as

```
Utilities.formatDate(event[0].getDateCreated(), tz, "E, dd MMMM YYYY hh:mm a")
```

instead - I want to convert by using a function attached to date object

as

```
event[0].getDateCreated().toLcl()
```

should accomplish the above task.

How do I define a toLcl()

I tried with

```
function toLcl()
{
    return Utilities.formatDate(this, tz, "E, dd MMMM YYYY hh:mm a")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ***JavaScript Date prototype Property***

The prototype constructor allows you to add new properties and methods to the Date() object.

```
Date.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    this.localDate = Utilities.formatDate(this, tz, "E, dd MMMM YYYY hh:mm a");

};
```

Use it like this :

```
var d = new Date();
d.myMethod();
var localDate = d.localDate;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Needs return statement in Date.prototype.myMethod in  my scenario

Answer (score 2):

You can add a property in the `prototype` of the `Date`. Do not alter the `prototype` directly. Use [`Object#defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead:

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, 'locale', {
  get: () => Utilities.formatDate(this, tz, "E, dd MMMM YYYY hh:mm a");
});

const myDate = new Date();
const localeDate = myDate.locale
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I invoke it?

Comment: @CodeGuy Make sure that the `definedProperty` is executed before the date returned by `event[0].getDateCreated()` is defined.